# Firebase Auth and Dialogflow agent

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, dialogflow-es

Can I use the telephone Firebase Auth code sent by SMS in a Dialogflow agent?

Like this: user receives the code by SMS and is prompted to call the Dialogflow agent that will ask for this code to finish the auth process.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final step of Firebase's phone number authentication to [sign the user in with their verification code as shown here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#sign-in-the-user-with-the-verification-code). As far as I can see this is only possible with the client-side SDKs of Firebase, which means that the sign-in must be completed on the device itself.

In DialogFlow you'd typically use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users). While the Admin SDK supports related operations ("Create a new user with a phone number without having to go through the SMS verification flow" and "Change a user's phone number without having to go through the SMS verification flow"), it doesn't allow you to verify that the user has control of the phone number based on the code that was texted to them.

Comment: Thank you very much @Frank! Im gonna dive into it, following your advice :-)